# area css (class or id or attr)

Tags: jquery, css, area

Is there any way to add atributes to an area tag?

What I want to do is on hover, change area opacity
when click change class (and of course apply attributes of this class)

I'm searching around and can't find any way to do it wihtout external plugins, is not a map, only an image with areas to click and change status and colors.

Any idea?

Comment: Which type of attribute?

Comment: at least background color and opacity.

Comment: You want to store some value in attributes

Comment: yup, but I'm testing and searching area CSS, and it doesn't have or I'm unable to find how to apply CSS on area (image area I mean)

Comment: ?? <area> are child of <map>, if no <map> then use a regular link tag. area can be styled in few browsers but it is not reliable. Else , id, class, data-attributes can be used on any tag.

Comment: then, is there another way to "map" a image? to make some areas clickables with divs maybe?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: i've decided to use divs and jquery much more flexible, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use divs and jquery, much more flexible and reliable